# Compilation error using Forest package

Tags: forest, compilation-error

I've been looking at this for a while, but can't figure out what's wrong with the code. It compiles in Overleaf, but with errors. I'll show the code first, and then the errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.4,0}

\newcommand{\both}{$p\underline{q}$}
\newcommand{\onlyP}{$p \underline{\neg q}$}
\newcommand{\onlyQ}{$\neg p\underline{q}$}
\newcommand{\neither}{$\neg p\underline{\neg q}$}

\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
sn edges/.style={for tree={circle, draw, thick, minimum size=1cm,inner sep=1,edge={->,thick}}}
}

\title{forest_test.tex}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
sn edges
[, phantom, s sep = 0.6cm
    [\both, mygreen, name=level0
        [\both, mygreen, edge=mygreen, name=level10, edge label = {node [midway,left] {$a$} }
            [\onlyP, red, edge=red, edge label = {node [midway,left] {$a$} }, name=level20]
            [\neither, red, edge=red, edge label = {node [midway, right] {$a$} }, name=level21] 
        ]
        [\onlyQ, mygreen, edge=mygreen, edge label = {node [midway,right] {$a$}}, name=level11
            [\onlyP, mygreen, edge=mygreen, edge label = {node [midway,left] {$a$}},name=level22  [\both, mygreen, edge=mygreen,name=h1, edge label = {node [midway,left] {$a$}} [\both, red, edge=red, edge label = {node [midway,left] {$a$}}] [\onlyQ, mygreen, edge=mygreen, edge label = {node [midway,right] {$a$}},name=h1new]] [\onlyQ, mygreen, edge=mygreen, name=h2, edge label = {node [midway,right] {$a$}} [\both, red, edge=red, edge label = {node [midway,left] {$a$}}] [\onlyQ, red, edge=red, edge label = {node [midway,right] {$a$}}] ]] 
            [\neither, mygreen, edge=mygreen , edge label = {node [midway,right] {$a$}}, name=level23 [\both, mygreen, edge=mygreen,name=h3new1, edge label = {node [midway,left] {$a$}} [\both, red, edge=red, edge label = {node [midway,left] {$a$}}] [\onlyQ, mygreen, edge=mygreen, edge label = {node [midway,right] {$a$}}, name=h2new] ] [\onlyQ, mygreen, edge=mygreen,name=h4, edge label = {node [midway,right] {$a$}} [\both, red, edge=red, edge label = {node [midway,left] {$a$}}] [\onlyQ, red, edge=red, edge label = {node [midway,right] {$a$}}]]] 
        ]   
    ]
    
    [\onlyQ, mygreen, name=level00
        [\both, mygreen, edge=mygreen,edge label = {node [midway,left] {$a$}}, name=level12
            [\onlyP, mygreen, edge=mygreen,edge label = {node [midway,left] {$a$}}, name=level24 [\both, mygreen, edge=mygreen,name=h5,edge label = {node [midway,left] {$a$}} [\both, red, edge=red, edge label = {node [midway,left] {$a$}}] [\onlyQ, red, edge=red, edge label = {node [midway,right] {$a$}}]] [\onlyQ, mygreen, edge=mygreen,name=h6,edge label = {node [midway,right] {$a$}} [\both, mygreen, edge=mygreen, edge label = {node [midway,left] {$a$}},name=h3new] [\onlyQ, red, edge=red, edge label = {node [midway,right] {$a$}}] ]] 
            [\neither, name=level25, mygreen, edge=mygreen,edge label = {node [midway,right] {$a$}} [\both, mygreen, edge=mygreen,name=h7,edge label = {node [midway,left] {$a$}} [\both, red, edge=red, edge label = {node [midway,left] {$a$}}] [\onlyQ, red, edge=red, edge label = {node [midway,right] {$a$}}]] [\onlyQ, mygreen, edge=mygreen,name=h8,edge label = {node [midway,right] {$a$}} [\both, mygreen, edge=mygreen, name=h4new, edge label = {node [midway,left] {$a$}}] [\onlyQ, red, edge=red, edge label = {node [midway,right] {$a$}}]]] 
        ]
        [\onlyQ, mygreen, edge=mygreen,edge label = {node [midway,right] {$a$}}, name=level13
            [\onlyP,name=level27, red, edge=red,edge label = {node [midway,left] {$a$}}] 
            [\neither,name=level28, red, edge=red ,edge label = {node [midway,right] {$a$}}] 
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

The intended output is:

[image]

The errors I get are:

```
     main.tex, line 44
Runaway argument?
{,afterthought={ 
! Paragraph ended before \forestOappto was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.44 \end{forest}
                 
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
 main.tex, line 44
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<argument> ...iven options}{,afterthought={ \par }
                                                  }
l.44 \end{forest}
                 
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
 main.tex, line 44
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<argument> ...ven options}{,afterthought={ \par }}
                                                  
l.44 \end{forest}
                 
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
```

Comment: remove the empty line in the middle of the tree.

Comment: thank you so much! I didn't realise the empty line could create a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is already solved by @Ulrike Fischer comment, however some remarks, which (to my opinion at least) can make your forest code shorter and more clear:

- your image is wider than standard article text width
- do you really need named all nodes in tree?
- positioning of edge labels can be automatically positioned (see MWE below)
- use of styles you can make your code significantly shorter

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames, margin=3mm]{standalone}% that whole image can be seen

\newcommand{\both}{$p\underline{q}$}
\newcommand{\onlyP}{$p \underline{\neg q}$}
\newcommand{\onlyQ}{$\neg p\underline{q}$}
\newcommand{\neither}{$\neg p\underline{\neg q}$}

\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.4,0}
\tikzset{
ELS/.style = {% Edge Label Style
              pos=0.4, node font=\footnotesize, 
              inner sep=2pt, anchor=#1},
        }
\newcommand\EC[1]{#1, edge=#1}


\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {% nodes
            circle, draw, semithick,
            minimum size=10mm, inner sep=0pt,
            % tree
            edge={-Straight Barb, semithick},
            s sep = 2mm,
            },% end for tree
EL/.style={% Edge Label, automatic positioning
           if n=1{edge label={node[ELS=east]{$#1$}}}
                 {edge label={node[ELS=west]{$#1$}}}
          },
EC/.style={color=#1, edge=#1}% coloring nodes and edges
[, phantom, 
% left tree
    [\both, EC=mygreen
        [\both, EC=mygreen, EL=a
            [\onlyP, EC=mygreen,  EL=a
                [\neither, EC=red, EL=a]
            ]
        ]
        [\onlyQ, EC=mygreen, EL=a
            [\onlyP, EC=mygreen, EL=a
                [\both,  EC=mygreen, EL=a
                    [\both,  EC=red,     EL=a]
                    [\onlyQ, EC=mygreen, EL=a]
                ] 
                [\onlyQ, EC=mygreen, EL=a
                    [\both, EC=red,  EL=a] 
                    [\onlyQ, EC=red, EL=a] 
                ]
            ]
            [\neither, EC=mygreen, EL=a
                [\both, EC=mygreen,EL=a
                    [\both, EC=red, EL=a] 
                    [\onlyQ, EC=mygreen, EL=a] 
                ]
                [\onlyQ, EC=mygreen, EL=a
                    [\both, EC=red,  EL=a]
                    [\onlyQ, EC=red, EL=a]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
% right tree
    [\onlyQ, EC=mygreen, 
        [\both, EC=mygreen, EL=a
            [\onlyP, EC=mygreen, EL=a
                [\both, EC=mygreen,  EL=a
                    [\both, EC=red,  EL=a] 
                    [\onlyQ, EC=red, EL=a]
                ] 
                [\onlyQ, EC=mygreen, EL=a
                    [\both, EC=mygreen, EL=a] 
                    [\onlyQ, EC=red,    EL=a] 
                ]
            ]
            [\neither, EC=mygreen,EL=a
                [\both, EC=mygreen, EL=a
                    [\both, EC=red, EL=a] 
                    [\onlyQ, EC=red, EL=a]
                ] 
                [\onlyQ, EC=mygreen,EL=a
                    [\both, EC=mygreen, EL=a] 
                    [\onlyQ, EC=red,    EL=a]
                ]
            ]
        ]
        [\onlyQ, EC=mygreen,  EL=a
            [\onlyP,EC=red,   EL=a]
            [\neither,EC=red, EL=a]
        ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]